# Error in variable

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Could you kindly help me in solving the following error.

```
 real(16), parameter :: &                                          
                              1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

the module containing the above code is as follows:

```
module degree_trig
    real(16), parameter :: &
            quadpi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
    real(16), parameter :: dgr_to_rad = (quadpi/180)
    intrinsic cos, sin, tan
      contains
    function sind(dgr_argument)
        real(4) sind, dgr_argument
            sind = sin(dgr_to_rad * dgr_argument)
    end function

    function cosd(dgr_argument)
        real(4) cosd, dgr_argument
            cosd = cos(dgr_to_rad * dgr_argument)
    end function

    function tand(dgr_argument)
        real(4) tand, dgr_argument
            tand = tan(dgr_to_rad * dgr_argument)
    end function

    function dsind(dgr_argument)
        real(8) dsind, dgr_argument
            dsind = sin(dgr_to_rad * dgr_argument)
    end function

    function dcosd(dgr_argument)
        real(8) dcosd, dgr_argument
            dcosd = cos(dgr_to_rad * dgr_argument)
    end function

    function dtand(dgr_argument)
        real(8) dtand, dgr_argument
            dtand = tan(dgr_to_rad * dgr_argument)
        end function
      end ! module
```

Comment: How do you compile this?  And could you perhaps find a more minimal example that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: Due to the uncertainties revealed in the comments, you should provide the exact compile command you use (including the file names) and the exact output of that command including all error messages. You should also make clear in your code which column is which, where is the first column of each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it compiles in gfortran 4.9.

But are yo sure that you saved it in a .f90 file?
What I mean is that the error looks like the compiler is expecting a fixed format.

By the way the value stored in the constant quadpi is not in quadruple precision. I suggest you to define a qp integer parameter (and sp, dp for single precision and double precision as well). Use the function selected_real_kind to store the kind value corresponding to quadruple precision, passing in the function the precision for that kind (that is 33 for quadruple precision, 15 for double precision, 6 for single precision).
You have to append _qp at the numeric constant (and _dp, and _sp for numeric constant of the other types).

I suggest you to write:

```
module degree_trig
implicit none

integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(6)
integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)
integer, parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind(33)

real(qp), parameter :: &
        quadpi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_qp
real(qp), parameter :: dgr_to_rad = (quadpi/180.0_qp)

contains
   elemental function sind(dgr_argument)
        real(sp), intent(in) :: dgr_argument
        real(sp) sind
        sind = sin(dgr_to_rad * dgr_argument)
   end function
```

Comment: rfsyn.f:32.30:

      real(qp), parameter :: &                                          
                              1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
rfsyn.f:33.72:

              quadpi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_qp     
                                                                        1
Error: Unexpected assignment statement in MODULE at (1)
rfsyn.f:34.49:

      real(qp), parameter :: dgr_to_rad = (quadpi/180_qp)               
                                                 1

Comment: I am using f77 to compile the above code. In spite of adding the code snippets that you had posted I got the errors posted in the last comment.rfsyn.f:32.30:

      real(qp), parameter :: &                                          
                              1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
rfsyn.f:33.72:

              quadpi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_qp     
                                                                        1
Error: Unexpected assignment statement in MODULE at (1)

Comment: @KuntalChaudhuri You CANNOT use f77, it is Fortran 90 or later!

Comment: Change the filename suffix to f90, as already suggested.  The file suffix .f causes gfortran to interpret the file in the older fixed-form syntax of FORTRAN 77.

Comment: well if I change the suffix to f90 then the comments that are written beginning with 'c' show error and then error limit reached.

Comment: Then replace all `c`s by `!`.

Comment: @KuntalChaudhuri The code you present isn't valid fixed-form code (even ignoring the `&` for line continuation) because of the column usage.  If it truly is meant to be fixed-form (which changes the validity of this answer), and that's the only why a comment starts with `c`,  then please format it correctly.

Comment: There is actually just one comment in the presented snippet and it is a `!`.

Comment: Can I send you the full code and then you can tell me how to get rid of the problems that are arising?

Comment: @KuntalChaudhuri edit the question with all the necessary details. Include the things I requested below the question, the FULL compilation command and the error messages. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suggest also to declare all functions `elemental`. That is: `elemental function sind(dgr_argument)`, etc.